# How to update one field and get back the entire entity in a single SQL statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE invoices SET
   version = o.version + 1
  ,modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ,business_no = $3::numeric
FROM invoices o
LEFT JOIN reps ON reps.rep_id = o.rep_id
LEFT JOIN terms ON terms.terms_id = o.terms_id
LEFT JOIN shipvia ON shipvia.ship_via_id = o.ship_via_id
WHERE o.id = $1::int AND CASE WHEN $2::numeric IS NULL THEN o.business_no IS NULL ELSE o.business_no = $2::numeric END
RETURNING o.id, o.version, o.business_no, ..., terms, rep, ship_via
```

It supposed to do the following:

1. Locate the desired invoice by its id ($1) and having the expected value in the business_no field ($2) set the business_no field to the new value ($3)
2. Advance the version field by one.
3. Return **all** the fields of the invoice after the update.

Unfortunately, it does not work as expected. Instead of updating just one invoice and returning the new version, it:

1. Updates all the invoices
2. Returns the pre-update version of the invoice duplicated N times, where N is the total count of the invoices.

I understand that my query is wrong, I am just failing to understand why and how to fix it.

Comment: You should **not** include the target table of the update in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are specifying invoices in the FROM list without tying it to the invoices table being UPDATEd.  The [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-update.html) warns about that.  So a simple fixup is as follows:

```
   UPDATE invoices i
      SET version = i.version + 1,
          modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          business_no = $3::numeric
     FROM           invoices o
          LEFT JOIN reps ON reps.rep_id = o.rep_id
          LEFT JOIN terms ON terms.terms_id = o.terms_id
          LEFT JOIN shipvia ON shipvia.ship_via_id = o.ship_via_id
    WHERE o.id = i.id
      AND o.id = $1::int
      AND (   (o.business_no IS NULL AND $2 IS NULL)
           OR (o.business_no = $2::numeric))
RETURNING i.id, i.version, i.business_no, i.modified, reps.name, terms.data, shipvia.who
```

I have an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f415a/6) showing that with hard coded values for the parameters.

However, since you seem to be only joining the secondary tables for the sake of the RETURNING clause, you might want to reorganise the whole thing:

```
WITH o AS (
     UPDATE invoices
        SET version = version + 1,
            modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            business_no = $3::numeric
      WHERE id = $1::int
        AND (   (business_no IS NULL AND $2 IS NULL)
             OR (business_no = $2::numeric))
  RETURNING *
) SELECT o.id, o.version, o.business_no, o.modified, reps.name, terms.data, shipvia.who
    FROM           o
         LEFT JOIN reps ON reps.rep_id = o.rep_id
         LEFT JOIN terms ON terms.terms_id = o.terms_id
         LEFT JOIN shipvia ON shipvia.ship_via_id = o.ship_via_id;
```

And the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f415a/13) updated to show the second version as well.  I cannot say whether it is better in this case, but it is an alternate technique that may be of benefit.

Comment: You should **not** include the target table of the update in the `FROM` clause.